# Would it be feasible to store/use an array with 200 thousand items?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, vb.net, performance

I have 239 text files to process in an application, at the moment the files are stored as resources and what I do is to load just one of the resources to an Array when I need to read the content of that file, when I finish to read the content I set the Array to `Nothing`, and I do the same for the other files when I need to read one of them.

Would be better If I load all the text-file contents of the 239 files into an Array at the loading of the application? that would sum an Array of about 200.000 item count.

Really what I think to do in a future is to generate an XML which contains all of the 239 text-file contents, and then load that XML into an object to manage the attributes/properties, but at the moment I don't have any idea of how to generate the XML either how to Read it right, but just by now knowing if an object/array of 200.000 lines/elements should be better to manage instead of reading some files/xml would be great to know for me.

Comment: What happens when the number and length of your files grows some more?

Comment: @Jon please what are you trying to say me?

Comment: The best approach would be buffering a small number of files at once and move forward just like a video is being played on the web.

Comment: @Elektro Jon said what happens when the number of files increases to, say, 5000 .. Are you going to load all the 5000 files onto the memory ?

Comment: if you want this to be scalable, you'll have to find a streaming approach.

Comment: Oh, A thing to notice is that the amount of text files could not increase more than 20 per each future year, sorry for not said that before. and the total filesize including 239 files are about 10 MB.

Comment: Still it increases ryt?? and you cannot load the whole content into memory as such. It won't scale

Comment: @ArunAravind if the expected size of future files is homogeneous and more or less the same as the 239 files he already has, it would take 10 years to grow the total size of all files an additional 4MB. It does not look like scaling will be a massive problem

Comment: English please.  To load them into array you read them one at a time.  If you process them one at a time then you read them one at a time.  You still read them one at a time.  Why would you take the memory hit of an array up front?

Comment: What is the total size of these 239 files?

Comment: @Miserable Variable 9,06 MB (9.504.115 bytes)

Comment: I think it is definitely feasible, you should try it out. If you don't expect the total size to grow a lot I see no reason to use database etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing we tend to forget: Window's excellent caching feature. If you just don't care about caching yourself and the reading procedure is fairly fast (e.g. one single `slurp`), you might ignore caching.

In other cases, I would recommend an extremely easy to implement "MRU cache" (MRU = most recently used). They are quite effective and implemented in a couple of minutes.

Say, you want to keep the 20 most often used files. Simply create a list. The list will hold the contents of each file (in an array) and the filename.

Each time you attempt to (re-read) the contents of a file, look in the list first. 
If it is in the list, move the contents to the front of the list and return the contents.
If it is not in the list, read the file and put it to the front of the list. If the list now contains more than 20 elements, discard the last element of the list.

You can increase '20' to your needs and will always have the top 20 most recently used list in memory.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
FileContents ReadFile(filename)
   i = List.IndexOf(filename) 
   if (i == NOTFOUND) 
     content = PhysicallyRead(filename)
   else
     content = List[i];
     List.RemoveItemAt(i);
   end
   List.InsertAt(0, content, filename)
   If List.Length > MAXLENGTH
     List.RemoveItemAt(MAXLENGTH)
```

I hope you get the idea. The only thing you have to take care about is that the list operations are fairly fast.

Using a database instead is generally the best approach, especially when you have to filter the file contents, do calculations on a row-by-row basis and so on. However, if speed is really crucial, an in-memory solution might be better.

But, if you want to keep it simple and extendible, consider using an embedded database solution (such as SQLite, Firebird embedded, SQL-Server embedded) as mentioned by the previous answers.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thankyou so much, I'm totally new with databases and would be really hard to start... I just have one question, to manage a database in vb.net first I need to install all the SQL packacges of the Microsoft VisualStudio installer?, I've installed just the necessary to develop in VB.NET, any SQL/C++/JS/OTHER package of the VS installer was installed.

Comment: I am not sure, to be honest. Afaik, your VS installation comes with a local SQL-Server (express) installation. You should find quite a few examples in the internet how to deal with databases. I always recommend that you'd get familiar with the server first, i.e. create tables, fill them etc. Also, you should really focus on what *not* to do, i.e. how to properly design your tables. Very easy, just follow a few rules. Then connect your VB.NET project with the database server and voilá, you've mastered DB basics.

Comment: This is good for memory conservation but not for performance, in my opinion. I have worked with files and it is definitely much slower than loading the data in memory. Implementing a cache is only useful if you have memory problems.

Comment: Absolutely correct. But by using a cache you don't have to care about scalability. However, I just read (somewhere in the comments) that the total filesize is 10MB (for all 239 files) and so indeed caching is  useless (here). You can also limit such a cache by the total size the cached elements occupy though. Still, the 10 MB will all fit into memory.

Answer (score 2):

The actual question is not *how many items* but *what is the total size of the items*. 10 MB is no problem in a system with 4 GB or more and, certainly, you can trust the system to page out accordingly. Loading all the data in an array will, most certainly, speed operations on them and you will avoid constant resizing of the array.

So, my opinion on this matter is that it can be better if you did load all the items, if you want to lighten disk load and improve processing performance.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of a single object.  In .NET 4.0 it is 1 GB and with fragmentation you only get about 1/2 that.  How does loading them up front avoid resizing? - up front does not know the total size.

Comment: @Blam I do stress that the real issue is the *size* of the items, don't I? 10MB is quite bellow the limit. After he uses the items, sets the Array to nothing. I say "constant resizing".

Comment: But you  site a system with 4 GB and that implies all memory is available.

Comment: @Blam No, that Implies that he will, obviously, need memory for other things to do with the computer.

Comment: What size are each item? 200,000 32-bit integers is about 780kb. 200,000 8kb blogs is about 1.5gb. And it matters if your array elements are value types or reference types. Value types are contained within the array proper; an array of reference types is an array of *references* to individual objects allocated on the heap. Further, the functional address space of a CLR app is about 1.4gb on a 32-bit system with 64-it systems not much better. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483475/Memory-Limits-in-a-NET-Process for more information.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey Indeed, very nice article. It is always nice to be reminded of the leaky abstractions we are dealing with every day.

Answer (score 1):

Even at 10 MB why take the memory hit.
Don't chance scale unless you have a specific performance issue.

With an array you need to size when you create it.
Do you know the know the size up front?

I would process a file at at time.
If the size if each file is the same then you can just re-use the same array for each file.

If you don't know the size of each file reuse a List a file at a time as it sizes to Capacity and Clear does not release capacity so you are not taking the hit of resizing.
Up front size set it to about what you expect the largest single file.

[List.Capacity Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx)

Comment: The question is if it would be "feasible" not if it would be the best practice. Just saying.

Comment: @ThunderGr But it would be "feasible" with 128 MB of memory.

Comment: I think that, performance-wise, it is faster to load everything in memory than implementing a "cache".

Comment: @ThunderGr Why you talking to me?  I said nothing about a cache.